# Error installing "could not get lock..."

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Error installing ROS on Ubuntu 11.04

Error in step 1.3:

Ign http://security.ubuntu.com natty-security/universe Translation-en
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com natty/restricted Sources [4,104 B]
Fetched 1,024 kB in 5s (194 kB/s)
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
ted@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Then similar error in step 1.4 (in the install instructions):

sudo apt-get install ros-diamondback-desktop-full

From the terminal, I get the error:

Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Help me please?  :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10838/error-installing-%22could-not-get-lock...%22/) by [teds](https://answers.ros.org/users/936/teds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-08-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some other process is using the package management.

Do you still have the update manager or synaptic or something similar open?
Or are you trying to install in parallel?

As the simplest solution a reboot should fix that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-08-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [teds](https://answers.ros.org/users/936/teds/) on 2011-08-06**:
Reboot worked!  XD